# Is there a more idiomatic way to cast json to a specific Hash type in Crystal?

Tags: json, crystal-lang

I've got a `JSON::Any`, and when I access the "params" key I get a `JSON::Any` representing this:

```json
{"a":0.9029593355545088,"b":2,"lh":1000,"ph":10,"pl":1}
```

I'd like to turn this into a `Hash(String, Float64)` and the simplest way I've found to do this is using `to_json` and then `from_json` since `Hash#from_json` doesn't accept the `JSON::Any` type.

```
params = Hash(String, Float64).from_json(json["params"].to_json)
```

It seems like I'm missing a concept or idiom somewhere. Is there a better way?

---

PS

If you want to play around with this, here's a snippet:

```
require "json"
json_string = %({"params": {"a": 1.2, "b": 2}})
json = JSON.parse(json_string)
Hash(String, Float64).from_json(json["params"].to_json)
```

Please note that in my code I don't have such easy access to `json_string`. Because it's buried in a much larger json response, I have to parse it to get down there and once parsed I have a `JSON::Any`. Thus it would seem I need to turn it back into a json string before I can turn it into a hash using `from_json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` returns a [`JSON::Any`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.35.1/JSON/Any.html), so you could use its handy casting helpers:

```
json["params"].as_h.transform_values(&.raw.as(Float64|Int64).to_f)
```

However if the structure is well defined, it's much better to make use of [`JSON::Serializable`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.35.1/JSON/Serializable.html):

```
record ApiResponse, params : Hash(String, Float64) do
  include JSON::Serializable
end

json_string = %({"params": {"a": 1.2, "b": 2}})
json = ApiResponse.from_json(json_string)
json.params # => {"a" => 1.2, "b" => 2.0}
```

Or even better yet:

```
record ApiResponse, params : ApiParams do
  include JSON::Serializable
end

record ApiParams, a : Float64, b : Float64 do
  include JSON::Serializable
end

json_string = %({"params": {"a": 1.2, "b": 2}})
json = ApiResponse.from_json(json_string)
json.params # => ApiParams(@a=1.2, @b=2.0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with that `record` macro (method?). Could you help me out with a link to some docs?

Also, am I right that none of these take `JSON::Any` as an argument. So if I already have `JSON::Any` I'll need to first go to a string `to_json` before I can do the above?

Comment: The suggestion here is to map your entire schema using these kinds of structs, replacing your entry point `JSON.parse` already and thus completely sidestepping `JSON::Any`.

[`record`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.35.1/toplevel.html#record(name,*properties)-macro) is just a handy shortcut to defining a `struct` with a couple of  [`property`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.35.1/Object.html#property(*names,&block)-macro)'s.

Comment: Oh I see now, so the more idiomatic way is to create matching structs and classes on the receiving end so that the entire JSON message is modeled. Of course, that makes sense now. Thank you!